# How do you control the (MSVS) VC lib directory that Gradle uses?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, gradle

I have a requirement where there will be two Microsoft Visual Studio builds (providing Visual Compiler) on a single machine, something like:

- C:\VisualStudio\2017\VisualCompiler\SoftwareKit\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64
- C:\VisualStudio\2017\VisualCompiler\SoftwareKit\10\Lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64

(This is how our IT deploys these installs so I cannot really control the layout)

For some Gradle builds (using the cpp-library and cpp-application Gradle plugins) I need to use one directory and for other Gradle builds I need to use the other.

How can I select between these two in my build.gradle scripts?

Comment: [Doesn't look like you can](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_cpp_projects.html#sec:cpp_supported_tool_chain)

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/

Answer (score 0):

From this post:

- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-override-the-toolchain-for-32bit-vs-64bit-cpp-builds/11107

This is the way:

```
toolChains {
    visualCpp32(VisualCpp) {
        windowsSdkDir winSdkDir32
        installDir visualCppDir32
    }
    visualCpp64(VisualCpp) {
        windowsSdkDir winSdkDir64
        installDir visualCppDir64
    }
}
```